# Is there a way to 'install' R packages without running install.packages()?

Tags: r, install.packages

We are testing how to run R in the cloud in a secure isolated environment that is blocked from CRAN and also cannot use packages.install(). We defined an environment which is based on R essentials Anaconda's bundle, still we would like to be able to customize it on demand with extra packages. Is there a way to be able to simulate packages.install(), e.g. by offline downloading the package, zip it, copy to the secure environment and unzipping it to a specific location in the library folder?

thanks!

Comment: You can have a private mini repo installed on your system from which it can be installed.  You may check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/create-a-local-package-repository-using-minicran?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If you have a same-configured system *with* access to CRAN, then you can install it there, zip up its installation directory, then copy into your secured environment; when you `install.packages(..)`, the only side-effect it has is creating and populating a new directory under your `.libPaths()[1]`, it doesn't update a registry somewhere with a list of installed packages. If R looks and a new directory just appears, then all is still good with the world. The only caveat is if the package requires OS-level libraries, which must also be installed somehow.

Comment: An installed package really is just a directory tree of files.  You can easily construct your own system of .tar.gz or .zip archives with whatever you want.  In fact, R can do that too for your via `R CMD INSTALL --build` -- which is what the RSPM files use too.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package from CRAN as a zip and then transport it to the isolated PC as a file. For example, here is the link to `dplyr` on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html

[image]

Then use the code below to install the local file:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/dplyr_1.0.7.zip", repos = NULL)
```

On Windows you might require [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html). At least there was a Warning about it but the package still installed.

For Linux machines, you can build the package from source using the tarball from the same page:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/dplyr_1.0.7.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

In both cases you need to take care of dependencies yourself as they are not checked while installing through this method (look at the "imports" field on the CRAN website for the package).

Comment: While it's no guarantee that an instance in the cloud is running unix or windows, I suspect that more instances of R "in the cloud" are not on windows, and the only binaries available there are for windows. Perhaps we need to verify the OS of the "cloud instance".

Comment: Well macOS has binaries at CRAN.  And 'off CRAN', OpenSUSE and Fedora have ~ 16k binaries, and Ubuntu has ~ 5k.  That is a good start.  Inaki and I have a paper on that I referenced a few times which describe this as well as installation  https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.08069

Comment: Sure ... sorry, I dismissed that "assuming" (my mistake) that remote cloud instances tend to be either windows or linux, not so much macs.

Comment: For whatever reason I thought that Linux users are probably aware they need to install the tarball instead, but it's a good idea to spell it out. I tested the above on my Linux machine and also on a Windows VM. The approach for macOS should be the same as binaries are available. There are also ways to pack binaries for Linux distributions. cran2deb for example. they seem too much work in this case though.

Comment: Thanks @JBGruber but the problem is that I cannot use install.packages() as creating sub-processes is blocked in my environment. So the question is if/how I can 'simulate' it, probably by creating manually the required directory structure?

Comment: I did not get that from your question and I did not know `install.packages` creates a sub-process. In this case the only option I see is to install the packages on a system with same cpu architecture and same OS and then copy the package folders over. Use `.libPaths()` to check where these folders are located.